# Make Gmail considering media="print"

Tags: html, email, gmail

When there is an email having elements with this media related class

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
   .no-print { display: none; }
</style>
```

these elements are regularly left out for printing while using Thunderbird, Outlook etc. Only Gmail embeds the mail's body for printing in it's own layout disregarding the media attribute, so that everything is printed.

How can I make Gmail behave like other mail clients for this? Is there a different way to markup HTML mail elements so that Gmail respects no print elements?

Answer (score 0):

you can try that :

```css
@media print {
  .no-print {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="no-print">This text will not be printed</p>
```

Comment: No, this serves the same result: Elements with this class are shown as if there is no CSS applied. When pressing "print" a new HTML page opens (with all content disregarding any "@media print") and from here the print dialogue is opened.